# Why don't buttons in mat-menus submit?

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I am using mat-menu to display a list of options for the user. When the user clicks on an option, it should trigger the submission of my formGroup.

*dropdown.component.html*

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)=onSubmit(myform)>
    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="options" type="submit">
        Options
    </button>
    <mat-menu #options="matMenu">
        <button mat-menu-item (click)="test()" type="submit">
                This is an Option //Submit formgroup when this button is clicked
        </button> 
    </mat-menu>
</form>
```

*dropdown.component.ts*

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'filter-dropdown',
    templateUrl: './filter-dropdown.component.html'
})

export class FilterDropdown implements OnInit{

    myForm: FormGroup;

    ngOnInit(){
        this.myForm = new FormGroup({});
    }

    onSubmit(form: FormGroup) {
        console.log('submitting...') //Only logs when 'Options' is clicked, not the mat-menu-item
    }

    test(){
        console.log('test has registered') //Logs when mat-menu-item is clicked
    }
}
```

When I click the `mat-menu-item`, the `test()` function is called, but not `onSubmit()`. Only when I remove the item from the mat menu and leave it as a standalone button is it able to call the submit function.

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)=onSubmit(myform)>
        <button mat-button type="submit">
            Options
        </button>
        <button (click)="test()" type="submit">
                    This is an Option //Submits now that it is no longer part of a mat-menu
        </button> 
 </form>
```

How can I get this button to submit while it is also an item of a `mat-menu`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens here is that the content of mat-menu component will be rendered outside of your form 
[image]

Here are several options you can use to make it working:

1) Submit form directly

```
<form #form="ngForm" ...>
  ...
  <mat-menu #options="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item (click)="form.onSubmit($event)" type="submit">
      ...
    </button> 
  </mat-menu>
</form>
```

> Please do note that `form.onSubmit()` call is better than
>   `form.ngSubmit.emit()` since it will set submitted flag on the form
>   and sync pending controls
>   https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4fe0e753659a9230901b7fa0563883d89b219a54/packages/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_group_directive.ts#L224, that is, your form will behave exactly the same if that submit button was inside your form

2) Use `form` attribute on button element to specify the form to be submitted(**doesn't work in IE**)

```
<form id="myForm" ...>
  ...
    <mat-menu #options="matMenu">
        <button mat-menu-item form="myForm" type="submit">
                ...
        </button> 
    </mat-menu>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the dropdown is rendered outside the form, you are unable to submit the form, so please pass the form reference using `[matMenuTriggerData]="{form: testForm}"` and inside the dropdown you can trigger the form submit using `(click)="form.ngSubmit.emit()"`, please check the below reference example!

<kbd>**Stack Blitz Demo**</kbd>